# Network switch time between replacement

Tags: switch

How often do you roll out new network switches/ how often are the older ones replaced?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I replace switches:

- When they fail
- When I need switches that support a new capability (1gb, PoE)

I rarely get rid of old working switches, but frequently they get moved into less critical roles.  The switches at the core are the ones where you usually need new features or capabilities.

Answer (score 1):

- Replace when they fail
- New features
- When the model is EOL or when vendor no longer supports device

Most manufactures support a EOL device for a few more years and depends on your support contracts!

Comment: Having a pool of cold spares can be cheap insurance to allow you to continue using EOL switches even after the manufacturer has decided (by way of ending support) that you should replace them.

Comment: +1 We have a lot of switches probably pushing a decade old that we really have absolutely no reason to replace.

Comment: +1 Evan's suggestion of keeping cold spares.

Answer (score 0):

In a very critical enviroment that would result in loosing a lot of money when the switch fails like in our enviroment (millions). We replace them every ten years.